# Can not remove folder with rm -rf

Tags: rm

I am using CMDER, while I try to remove a large folder with command 'rm -rf' the terminal freezes. It seems that rm process is running, but without expected result. I tried to create a new folder with the same permissions, then remove it and command worked. It seems that it is caused by the folder I want to remove. Manually (by clicking), I can remove that folder.

Why such strange behaviour?

Comment: How many files and subdirectories are in this folder? I suspect the rm command has to remove each one individually so it would take a lot of time if there were thousands.

Comment: Many, it is big java project with many subfolders. I waited something like 2 min without any result. By clicking on Win 10, it was removed immediately.

Comment: "By clicking on Win 10, it was removed immediately" -- removed or moved to recycle bin?

Comment: Removed from recycle bin.